# Data analysis and computing heat index from temperature and humidity data to graph in Python

Tags: python, time-series, data-analysis

So I'm trying to calculate heat index from the data that 13 different sensors upload into a shared google drive. A picture of what the data looks like is attached here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDCWQ.png. All the data is compiled from all the sensors into one document, with one document for each day. I am trying to calculate the heat index using the equations linked here: [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuEGQ.png), using the temperature and humidity values listed. I want to compute heat index values for each individuals sensor, and graph them on a time series plot, with 13 different lines for the different sensors. In my code attached I already have created time series for the temperature and humidity as separate graphs.

here is my current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, HourLocator
import os
import re
import math


def CreateFileList(startdate,enddate):
    currentdate=startdate
    filelist=[]
    while currentdate <= enddate:
        formatdate= currentdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        filename = f'iseechange-sensor-data-mdc-heat-and-transit-{formatdate}-sensors.csv'
        filelist.append(filename)
        currentdate+=timedelta(days=1)
    return filelist

def CalculateHeatIndex(T,H):


        
        heatindexsimple = 0.5 * (T + 61.0 + ((T - 68.0) * 1.2) + (H * 0.094))
        if heatindexsimple >= 80.0:
            heatindex = -42.379 + 2.04901523 * T + 10.14333127 * H - 0.22475541 * T * H - 0.00683783 * T**2 - 0.05481717 * H**2 + 0.00122874 * T**2 * H + 0.00085282 * T * H**2 - 0.00000199 * T**2 * H**2
        
            if H < 13 and 80 <= T <= 112:
                adjustment = ((13 - H) / 4) * math.sqrt((17 - abs(T - 95.0)) / 17)
                heatindex -= adjustment
        
            if H > 85 and 80 <= T <= 87:
                adjustment = ((H - 85) / 10) * ((87 - T) / 5)
                heatindex += adjustment
        
           
            return (heatindex)
        
        
       
        return (heatindexsimple)        
        
def ReadSensorData(filename,currentdate,nheaders=0):
     Time1=[]
     Temperature=[]
     SensorID1=[]
     Humidity=[]
     Time2=[]
     SensorID2=[]
     SensorID3=[]
     Time3=[]
     
     currenttemp={}
     currenthumidity= {}
     lastsensorID= None 
     HeatIndex=[]
     lasttype= None

     
     with open(filename,'r') as fobjs:    
         linelist = fobjs.readlines()                
     

     for line in linelist[nheaders:]:
         line=line.strip()
         words=line.strip('"').split('","')
         
         if len(words)==5 and words[3]=='humidity':
            humidityvalue=(float(words[4]))
            Humidity.append(humidityvalue)
            timestamp2=f"{words[0]} {words[1]}"
            currenthumidity[words[2]]= humidityvalue
            try:
                 fixedtime2=datetime.strptime(timestamp2,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            except ValueError:
                 fixedtime2=datetime.strptime(timestamp2,'%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d')   
            formattime2 = fixedtime2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            Time2.append(formattime2)
            SensorID2.append(words[2])
            if lasttype == 'temperature':
                heatindex= CalculateHeatIndex(currenttemp[lastsensorID],humidityvalue)
                HeatIndex.append(heatindex)
                Time3.append(formattime2)
                SensorID3.append(words[2])
                lasttype= None
            
            else:
                lasttype= 'humidity'
            lastsensorID=words[2]
                
        
         elif len(words)==5 and words[3]=='temperature':
            Ctemp=(float(words[4].strip()))
            Temperature.append(Ctemp)
            Ftemp=(Ctemp * 9/5) + 32
            timestamp1=f"{words[0]} {words[1]}"
            currenttemp[words[2]]= Ftemp
            try:
                 fixedtime1=datetime.strptime(timestamp1,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            except ValueError:
                 fixedtime1=datetime.strptime(timestamp1,'%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d')   
            formattime1 = fixedtime1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            Time1.append(formattime1)
            SensorID1.append(words[2])
            if lasttype == 'humidity':
                heatindex= CalculateHeatIndex(Ftemp,currenthumidity[lastsensorID])
                HeatIndex.append(heatindex)
                Time3.append(formattime1)
                SensorID3.append(words[2])
                lasttype= None
                
            else:
                lasttype= 'temperature'
            lastsensorID=words[2]
            

  
     return Temperature,Time1,SensorID1,Humidity,Time2,SensorID2, HeatIndex, Time3, SensorID3      


def CreateAllData(filelist,folderpath,n=3):
    alltemps=[]
    alltimes1=[]
    allsensorids1=[]
    allhumidity=[]
    alltimes2=[]
    allsensorids2=[]
    allsensorids3=[]
    alltimes3=[]
    allHI=[]
    datepattern=r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
    for filename in filelist:
        match=re.search(datepattern,filename)
        if match:
            
            
            datepart=match.group(0)
            currentdate=datetime.strptime(datepart,'%Y-%m-%d')
            fullfilepath=os.path.join(folderpath,filename)
            Temperature,Time1,SensorID1,Humidity,Time2,SensorID2, HeatIndex, Time3, SensorID3= 

ReadSensorData(fullfilepath,currentdate,nheaders=0)
            numsamples1=len(Temperature)
            subsamples1=range(0,numsamples1,n)
            subsampletemp=[Temperature[i] for i in subsamples1]
            subsampletime1=[Time1[i] for i in subsamples1]
            alltemps.extend(subsampletemp)
            alltimes1.extend(subsampletime1)
            allsensorids1.extend(SensorID1)
            
            numsamples2=len(Humidity)
            subsamples2=range(0,numsamples2,n)
            subsamplehumidity=[Humidity[i] for i in subsamples2]
            subsampletime2=[Time2[i] for i in subsamples2]
            allhumidity.extend(subsamplehumidity)
            alltimes2.extend(subsampletime2)
            allsensorids2.extend(SensorID2)
            
            numsamples3=len(HeatIndex)
            subsamples3=range(0,numsamples3,n)
            subsampleHI=[HeatIndex[i] for i in subsamples3]
            subsampletime3=[Time3[i] for i in subsamples3]
            alltimes3.extend(subsampletime3)
            allsensorids3.extend(SensorID3)
            allHI.extend(subsampleHI)
            
            
            
        else:
            print('error')
     
    return alltemps,alltimes1,allsensorids1,allhumidity,alltimes2,allsensorids2,allHI, alltimes3,allsensorids3


def OrganizeBySensor(UniqueSensor, allsensorids1,alltemps,alltimes1,allsensorids2,allhumidity,alltimes2,allsensorids3,allHI,alltimes3):
    finaldata1={}
    finaldata2={}
    finaldata3={}

    for ID in UniqueSensor:
        IDTemp = [(temp, datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) for temp, sensorID, time in zip(alltemps, allsensorids1, alltimes1) if sensorID == ID]
        finaldata1[ID]={'temp': [data[0] for data in IDTemp], 'time': [data[1] for data in IDTemp]}
    
   
    for ID in UniqueSensor:
        IDHumidity = [(humidity, datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) for humidity, sensorID, time in zip(allhumidity, allsensorids2, alltimes2) if sensorID == ID]
        finaldata2[ID]={'humidity': [data[0] for data in IDHumidity], 'time': [data[1] for data in IDHumidity]}
    
    
    for ID in UniqueSensor:
        IDHI = [(HI, datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) for HI, sensorID, time in zip(allHI, allsensorids3, alltimes3) if sensorID == ID]
        finaldata3[ID]={'heat index': [data[0] for data in IDHI], 'time': [data[1] for data in IDHI]}
        
        
    return finaldata1,finaldata2,finaldata3

def CalculateRollingMean(data,windowsize):
    rollingavg=[]
    for i in range(len(data)-windowsize+1):
        window=data[i:i+windowsize]
        avg= sum(window)/windowsize
        rollingavg.append(avg)
    return rollingavg

def ReadWSData(filename2,filename3,nheaders2=0,nheaders3=0):
    Time2=[]
    Temperature2=[]
    Time3=[]
    Humidity3=[]
    WSTemperatureF=[]
    
    with open(filename2,'r') as fobjs:    
        linelist = fobjs.readlines()                
    

    for line in linelist[nheaders2:]:
        words=line.split(',')
        Temperature=(float(words[2]))
        WSTemperatureF.append(Temperature)
        Temperature2.append((Temperature-32)*(5/9))
        Time2.append(datetime.strptime(words[1],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        
    with open(filename3,'r') as fobjs:    
        linelist2 = fobjs.readlines()                
        

    for line in linelist2[nheaders3:]:
        words2=line.split(',')
        Humidity3.append(float(words2[2]))
        Time3.append(datetime.strptime(words2[1],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))



    return Temperature2,Time2,Humidity3,Time3,WSTemperatureF


    
def CalculateWSHeatIndex(T,H):


        
        heatindexsimple = 0.5 * (T + 61.0 + ((T - 68.0) * 1.2) + (H * 0.094))
        if heatindexsimple >= 80.0:
            heatindex = -42.379 + 2.04901523 * T + 10.14333127 * H - 0.22475541 * T * H - 0.00683783 * T**2 - 0.05481717 * H**2 + 0.00122874 * T**2 * H + 0.00085282 * T * H**2 - 0.00000199 * T**2 * H**2
        
            if H < 13 and 80 <= T <= 112:
                adjustment = ((13 - H) / 4) * math.sqrt((17 - abs(T - 95.0)) / 17)
                heatindex -= adjustment
        
            if H > 85 and 80 <= T <= 87:
                adjustment = ((H - 85) / 10) * ((87 - T) / 5)
                heatindex += adjustment
        
       
            return (heatindex)
        
      
        return (heatindexsimple)
        

    
    
                     

def main():
    startdate= datetime(2023,8,25)
    enddate=datetime(2023,11,8)
    folderpath='/Users/ericschmitt/Documents/Heat Project Data'
    filename2=os.path.join(folderpath,'HechtACWeatherstem.csv')
    filename3=os.path.join(folderpath,'HechtACWeatherstemHumidity.csv')
    nheaders2,nheaders3=1,1
    filelist= CreateFileList(startdate,enddate)
    alltemps,alltimes1,allsensorids1,allhumidity,alltimes2,allsensorids2,allHI,alltimes3,allsensorids3=CreateAllData(filelist,folderpath)
    UniqueSensor=set(allsensorids1)
    finaldatatemp,finaldatahumidity,finaldataheatindex=OrganizeBySensor(UniqueSensor, allsensorids1,alltemps,alltimes1,allsensorids2,allhumidity,alltimes2,allsensorids3,allHI,alltimes3)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(35,10))
    fig2,ax2= plt.subplots(figsize=(35,10))
    fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots(figsize=(35,20))
    Temperature2,Time2,Humidity3,Time3,WSTemperatureF=ReadWSData(filename2,filename3,nheaders2,nheaders3)
    windowsize1=4
    for ID, data in finaldatatemp.items():
        sensorlabel=ID[-4:]
        rollingtemp= CalculateRollingMean(data['temp'],windowsize1)
        rollingtime1=data['time'][windowsize1-1:]
        ax.plot(rollingtime1,rollingtemp,label=f'SensorID:{sensorlabel}')
    ax.plot(Time2,Temperature2, label='UM Hecht Athletic Center Weatherstem',color='black')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax.set_ylabel('Temperature(Degrees Celsius)')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%m-%d'))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator(interval=96))
    ax.set_title('Time vs Temperature for ISeeChange Sensor Data from 8/25-11/08')
    ax.axis('auto')
    ax.legend(loc='upper left')


    windowsize2=6
    for ID, data in finaldatahumidity.items():
        sensorlabel=ID[-4:]
        rollinghumidity= CalculateRollingMean(data['humidity'],windowsize2)
        rollingtime2=data['time'][windowsize2-1:]
        ax2.plot(rollingtime2,rollinghumidity,label=f'SensorID:{sensorlabel}')
    ax2.plot(Time3,Humidity3, label='UM Hecht Athletic Center Weatherstem',color='black')
    ax2.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Humidity')
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%m-%d'))
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator(interval=96))
    ax2.set_title('Time vs Humidity for ISeeChange Sensor Data from 8/25-11/08')
    ax2.axis('auto')
    ax2.legend(loc='upper left')


    WSheatindexdata=[CalculateWSHeatIndex(T,H) for T,H in zip(WSTemperatureF,Humidity3)]
    WSheatindexdata=list(WSheatindexdata)
    for ID, data in finaldataheatindex.items():
        sensorlabel=ID[-4:]
        HItimes = data['time']
        heatindex = data['heat index']
        ax3.plot(HItimes,heatindex,label=f'SensorID:{sensorlabel}')
           
    ax3.plot(Time3,WSheatindexdata, label='UM Hecht Athletic Center Weatherstem',color='black')
    ax3.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax3.set_ylabel('Heat Index(Degrees F)')
    ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%m-%d'))
    ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator(interval=96))
    ax3.set_title('Time vs Heat Index for ISeeChange Sensor Data from 8/25-11/08')
    ax3.axis('auto')
    ax3.legend(loc='upper left')  
    plt.show()
        
        
        
main()
```

If possible could you debug this code as a whole, my temperature and humidity graphs looked somewhat right, but i'm sure they could be improved, they are linked here:[TempGraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxQ6V.png). [Humidity graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZyTC.png) Mainly my heat index graph that I got here: [Heat Index graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhhdL.png). The heat index graph doesn't look fully right because I got calculated values of over 250 degrees F, which is crazy high values for heat index. Something must be going wrong with the code. The black lines on all the graph are data from a nearby weather station that are being used to compare the results from the sensors, and are unrelated to the sensors.

I tried a lot of debugging and am still not getting the results that I wanted. I included the calculation of the heat index into the actual reading of the data, because there are some discrepancies in the data and wasn't able to just use the long lists of temperature and heat index values to calculate the heat index because they didn't align correctly in length. Because of this I went the route of as it reads the data it records the value of either humidity or temperature, whichever comes first. It then moves down the lines in the file until it either gets the missing value, it then calculates heat index using those two values and adds it to a list. Then it resets the values and repeats the process. From there I have another function that iterates through all of the files which then compiles all of the heat index values and its associated time and sensor id values. It then sorts it by sensor ID into a dictionary that should allow me to graph the time vs heat index. I thought my logic was sound, but it isn't working correctly. I don't think heat index values should get over 130 at the very maximum in Miami, so some of the values calculated are definitely incorrect.

Comment: `I am trying to calculate the heat index using the equations linked here:` Should there be an image of equations here?

Comment: https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/html/heatindex_equation.shtml  The equations linked here sorry